# Django does assign but not store primary key value

Tags: django, model, sqlite

I have a simple django model

```
class Directory(models.Model):

  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  path = models.TextField(unique=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.path

  class Meta:
    db_table = u'directories'
```

However, there seems to be some problem to save a Directory instance into the db

```
>>> from cygapp.models import Directory
>>> d = Directory()
>>> d.path = '/usr'
>>> d.id
>>> d.save()
>>> d.id
4
>>> d
<Directory: /usr>
```

while the ID field is assigned correctly (the next free value), it is not stored in the db

```
sqlite> select * from directories;
1|/bin
2|/system/lib
3|/system/bin
|/usr
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: django automatically assigns an id field to your models, you don't need it to declare it manually. also, try to remove your unicode method and see if it then prints your id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you're doing to save the record is correct and an auto id should be assigned.

Remove your custom id field `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` since Django does this automatically for you.  Then drop your 'directories' table and run `python manage.py syncdb`.  This will ensure you have a correct id field on your model.

Comment: I'm aware that django creates an id automatically, but since I have to adapt my models to an existing database I want to control everything myself, I also cannot simply run `syncdb` because I want the `django_*` and `auth_*` tables to be stored in a separate db. but dropping the table and recreating it from the `manage.py` generated sql solved the issue (whyever). I'll therefore mark this as the correct answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: Are you using the multi_db deployment (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)?  That should allow you to use the syncdb mechanism and store your user data in a separate db.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do. What I haven't done yet, is implementing `allow_syncdb`. I will get to that immediately. Thanks again!